# How to get modified less file for download?

Tags: css, less

I have referred a less file in the web page which has an imported file and I can change the variables using less.modifyVars method. Now I want to download the modified import less file, not parsing the CSS output. Is there any way to get the modified less file after using modifyVars?

For Example

Web.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="theme.less" />
```

base.less:

```
@header: #ffffff;
```

theme.less:

```
@import base.less;
.header{
  color: @header;
}
```

common.js:

```
less.modifyVars({"header", "#000000"});
```

I want to get the modified base.less file with changes @header: #000000; Can I get the file?

Comment: where are you looking to export your less.file

Comment: I have to download the modified less file from web

Comment: Is it available in developer tools network tab?

Comment: Yes its there, but the variable changes not reflected

Comment: `modifyVars` simply appends its value to the master source code string (e.g. for your example  `less.modifyVars({"header", "#000000"});` is equal to appending `@header: #000000;` to `theme.less`), thus to "get" the modified file you can perform the concatenation on your own. As for "download", no such modified file is really created by the compiler (nor the modified source code string is stored anywhere), so no, you can't download it via Less compiler script itself. So it completely up to you to create such file using whatever suitable facilities (e.g. via your own script code).